# How to rotate object with array modifier without problems in blender

Tags: modifiers

I am new to blender.
I modeled the clock with an array modifier and only then realized that I needed to rotate the entire object 90 degrees. But when I try, the array gets distorted and everything breaks. How can you rotate everything without any deformations and changes??

Comment: if you've used an object as Object Offset, rotate it as well

Comment: ... even parent one to the other, so they always move together

Answer (score 1):

## In this case, the cube global Rotation is 0,0,0

[image]

## delete the array modifier and copy two cube to this position

[image]

## Setup the array modifiers with object offset

[image]

## Hide the 2 cube in final